# Order a list depending on other list

Tags: c++, stl

Given:

```
struct Object {
    int id;
    ...
};

list<Object> objectList;
list<int> idList;
```

What is the best way to order `objectList` depending on order of `idList`?

Example (pseudo code):

```
INPUT
    objectList = {o1, o2, o3};
    idList = {2, 3, 1};

ACTION
    sort(objectList, idList);

OUTPUT
    objectList = {o2, o3, o1};
```

I searched in documentation but I only found methods to order elements comparing among themselves.

Comment: Have you tried passing a comparator function to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: Do you have one Object per id ? and is you id unique? Because otherwise the best way would be to use a Map

Comment: @basslo multimap, if id is not unique...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `std::sort` requires random-access iterators, but `std::list` has its own `sort` member function.

Comment: Just for clarification, there are two interpretations of the meaning the content of idList present (compare overseas' to kebs' answers): If o1, o2 and o3 had the ids 10, 12, 7, then idList's content would be 12, 7, 10 (overseas) -- or still 2, 3, 1 (kebs) (latter one rather inducing the name 'indexList')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the objects in an `std::map`, with `id` as key. Then traverse `idList`, get the object out of `map` with its `id`.

```
std::map<int, Object> objectMap;
for (auto itr = objectList.begin(); itr != objectList.end(); itr++)
{
    objectMap.insert(std::make_pair(itr->id, *itr));
}

std::list<Object> newObjectList;
for (auto itr = idList.begin(); itr != idList.end(); itr++)
{
    // here may fail if your idList contains ids which does not appear in objectList
    newObjectList.push_back(objectMap[*itr]);
}

// now newObjectList is sorted as order in idList
```

Comment: Idea is fine, but needs a small correction: you need to iterate over both lists at the same time (`for(...; ...; ++it_id, ++it_obj)`) and make your pairs from both iterators then (`std::make_pair(*it_id, *it_obj);`) (sort order is given  in the second list!).

Comment: @Aconcagua In second `for` loop, `itr` is iterator of `idList`, which stores all the ids. Therefore, `*itr` is `id`, which is the key of `objectMap`.

Comment: The ids in the object's list could be completely unrelated to the sort order, resulting in entirely unpredictable results! Do not sort at all by the object's id, sort directly by index. Advantage: you then can just use an ordinary iterator over the map to get the order right!

Comment: Imagine id list is simply { 1, 2, 3 } (identity), object ids are {12, 7, 10}. What would be the result???

Comment: @Aconcagua You are right. I didn't think for these exceptions.

Comment: this is of course an easier approach than mine below, but using a map will be much slower when the list is large. So when performance counts, this approach will be pretty bad due to rebalancing (eventhough it is asymptotically optimal too), while when simplicity counts, this approach is great. In general a map is not that useful if you insert the elements only once, because then you can just use a vector and sort as I did below.

Comment: Just discovered that I probably misinterpreted the question - it is **"idList"**, not **"indexList"**, so the contents of this list should presumably be exactly the ids of the the objects list... Sorry for trouble.

Comment: In my post below I added some simple measurements why this code is much slower than using a vector-based approach.

Comment: @overseas Well, here we are trading efficiency against simplicity. I'd prefer simplicity, if it is clear that we are handling only small data (better code maintainability!), but efficiency, if expecting large data sets or if the size of data is unknown (e. g. in libraries designed for general use).

Comment: Nothing can be preferred as long as the usecase is unknown. This is why I mentionned both, simplicity and performance, which can both be important in different circumstances. And this is why none of the approaches is better in general.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another variant, which works in `O(n log n)`. This is asymptotcally optimal.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
  struct O {
    int id;
  };
  std::list<O> object_list{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
  std::list<int> index_list{4, 2, 3, 1};
  assert(object_list.size() == index_list.size());

  // this vector is optional. It is needed if sizeof(O) is quite large.
  std::vector<std::pair<int, O*>> tmp_vector(object_list.size());
  // this is O(n)
  std::transform(begin(object_list), end(object_list), begin(tmp_vector),
                 [](auto& o) { return std::make_pair(o.id, &o); });
  // this is O(n log n)
  std::sort(begin(tmp_vector), end(tmp_vector), 
            [](const auto& o1, const auto& o2) {
            return o1.first < o2.first;
            });
  // at this point, tmp_vector holds pairs in increasing index order. 
  // Note that this may not be a contiguous list.

  std::list<O> tmp_list(object_list.size());
  // this is again O (n log n), because lower_bound is O (n)
  // we then insert the objects into a new list (you may also use some 
  // move semantics here).
  std::transform(begin(index_list), end(index_list), begin(tmp_list),
                 [&tmp_vector](const auto& i) {
                   return *std::lower_bound(begin(tmp_vector), end(tmp_vector),
                                            std::make_pair(i, nullptr),
                                            [](const auto& o1, const auto& o2) {
                                              return o1.first < o2.first;
                                            })->second;
                 });

  // As we just created a new list, we swap the new list with the old one.
  std::swap(object_list, tmp_list);

  for (const auto& o : object_list)
    std::cout << o.id << std::endl;

}
```

I assumed that O is quite large and not easily movable. Therefore i first create `tmp_vector` which only contains of pairs. Then I sort this vector.

Afterwards I can simply go through the `index_list` and find the matching indices using binary search.

---

Let me elaborate on why a map is not the best solution eventhough you get a quite small piece of code. If you use a map you need to rebalance your tree after each insertion. This doesn't cost asympatotically (because n times rebalancing costs you the same as sorting once), but the constant is way larger. A "constant map" makes not that much sense (except accessing it may be easier).

I then timed the "simple" map-approach against my "not-so-simple" vector-approach. I created a randomly sorted `index_list` with `N` entries. And this is what I get (in us):

```
N         map         vector
1000      90          75
10000     1400        940
100000    24500       15000
1000000   660000      250000
```

NOTE: This test shows the worst case as in my case only index_list was randomly sorted, while the object_list (which is inserted into the map in order) is sorted. So rebalancing shows all its effect. If the object_list is kind of random, performance will behave more similar, eventhough performance will always be worse. The vector list will even behave better when the object list is completely random.

So already with 1000 entries the difference is already quite large. So I would strongly vote for a vector-based approach.

Comment: `std::make_pair(o.id, &o)` You sort by object ids here! These could be totally unrelated to the problem given! Imagine ids list is {1, 2, 3} (identity), object ids are {12, 7, 10}.

Comment: You are wrong and should give it a try. Yes I sort by object ids there, afterwards you can simply lookup with binary search.

Comment: Just discovered that I probably misinterpreted the question - it is **"idList"**, not **"indexList"**, so the contents of this list should presumably be exactly the ids of the the objects list... Sorry for trouble.

Comment: Yes the wording of the question is not that useful, it is the example that shows how the sorting is required.

Comment: The example does really do so - 2, 3, 1 could be interpreted as (one-based) indices, too (just as kebs does in his answer - and as I did initially). If o1, o2, o3 had ids 10, 12, 7, for instance, and idList was 7, 10, 12 - *then* the example would have been really clear...

Comment: In addition to your speed thoughts: vector additionally has the advantage of contiguous memory...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is handled to you externally and you don't have the choice of the containers:

```
assert( objectList.size() == idList.size() );
std::vector<std::pair<int,Object>> wrapper( idList.size() );
auto idList_it     = std::begin( idList );
auto objectList_it = std::begin( objectList );
for( auto& e: wrapper )
    e = std::make_pair( *idList_it++, *objectList_it++ );
std::sort(
    std::begin(wrapper),
    std::end(wrapper),
    []
    (const std::pair<int,Object>& a, const std::pair<int,Object>& b) -> bool
    { return a.first<b.first; }
);
```

Then, copy back to original container.

```
{
   auto objectList_it = std::begin( objectList );
   for( const auto& e: wrapper )
      *objectList_it++ = e;
}
```

But this solution is not optimal, I'm sure somebody will come with a better solution.

**Edit**: The default comparison operator for pairs requires that it is defined both for first and second members. Thus the easiest way is to provide a lambda.

**Edit2**: for some reason, this doesn't build if using a `std::list` for the wrapper. But it's ok if you use a `std::vector` ([see here](http://ideone.com/Sc83NX)).

Comment: It does not work with list, but with vector, because std::sort requires random access iterators, which list's iterators are *not*...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah, was sure it was related to that but was too lazy to dig, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` has a `sort` member function you can use with a custom comparison functor.

That custom functor has to look up an object's `id` in the `idList` and can then use `std::distance` to calculate the position of the element in `idList`. It does so for both objects to be compared and returns true if the first position is smaller than the second.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Object
{
    int id;
};

int main()
{
    Object o1 = { 1 };
    Object o2 = { 2 };
    Object o3 = { 3 };
    std::list<Object> objectList = { o1, o2, o3 };
    std::list<int> const idList = { 2, 3, 1 };

    objectList.sort([&](Object const& first, Object const& second)
    {
        auto const id_find_iter1 = std::find(begin(idList), end(idList), first.id);
        auto const id_find_iter2 = std::find(begin(idList), end(idList), second.id);
        if (id_find_iter1 == end(idList) || id_find_iter2 == end(idList))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("ID not found");
        }
        auto const pos1 = std::distance(begin(idList), id_find_iter1);
        auto const pos2 = std::distance(begin(idList), id_find_iter2);
        return pos1 < pos2;
    });

    for (auto const& object : objectList)
    {
        std::cout << object.id << '\n';
    }
}
```

It's probably not terribly efficient, but chances are you will never notice. If it still bothers you, you might want to look for a solution with `std::vector`, which unlike `std::list` provides random-access iterators. That turns `std::distance` from O(n) to O(1).

Comment: `chances are you will never notice`: Mmmh, you are making an assumption on the size of the OP data. Maybe he has dazillions of these ?

Comment: @kebs: Yes, I make an assumption (hence "probably" and "chances are"), based not the least on the fact that the OP uses `std::list`, which is already one of the generally slower data structures. If you need to be fast, then you typically use `std::vector` and not `std::list`.

Comment: Agree, but maybe the OP chose list specifically because he has a lot of insertions, on which large vectors are slower than list ? As always, "best" container is a matter of what you "mostly" do with it.

Comment: What, if requirement is e. g. iterators not getting invalidated on insertions/deletions? vectors cannot guarantee this condition, so you are forced to use a list, even on large data...

Comment: @kebs: `std::vector` should be faster than `std::list` even for operations where `std::list` provides better computational complexity, all thanks to cache locality. The reason for using `std::list` is that iterators do not become invalid when the rest of the list changes.

Comment: @Aconcagua: If iterators need to remain valid and the speed of `std::list` is unacceptable, then some `std::unordered_map`-based solution may be fine.

Comment: @ChristianHackl std::unordered_map does not guarantee either!

Comment: @Aconcagua: Right, if rehashing occurs. Well, I'd say the OP had better state more detailed requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

I would find it strange to end up in this situation as I would use the pointers instead of the ids. Though; there might be usecases for this.

Note that in all examples below, I assume that the ids-list contains all ids exactly ones.

### Writing it yourself

The issue you like to solve is creating/sorting a list of objects based on the order of the ids in another list.

The naive way of doing this, is simply writing it yourself:

```
void sortByIdVector(std::list<Object> &list, const std::list<int> &ids)
{
    auto oldList = std::move(list);
    list = std::list<Object>{};
    for (auto id : ids)
    {
        auto itElement = std::find_if(oldList.begin(), oldList.end(), [id](const Object &obj) { return id == obj.id; });
        list.emplace_back(std::move(*itElement));
        oldList.erase(itElement);
    }
}
```

If you use a sorted vector as input, you can optimize this code to get the best performance out of it. I'm leaving it up-to you to do so.

### Using sort

For this implementation, I'm gonna assume this are std::vector instead of std::list, as this is the better container to request the index of an element. (You can with some more code do the same for list)

```
size_t getIntendedIndex(const std::vector<int> &ids, const Object &obj)
{
    auto itElement = std::find_if(ids.begin(), ids.end(), [obj](int id) { return id == obj.id; });
    return itElement - ids.begin();
}

void sortByIdVector(std::list<Object> &list, const std::vector<int> &ids)
{
     list.sort([&ids](const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs){ return getIntendedIndex(ids, lhs) < getIntendedIndex(ids, rhs); });
}
```

### Insertion

Another approach, also more suitable for std::vector would be simply inserting the elements at the right place and will be more performant than the std::sort.

```
void sortByIdVector(std::vector<Object> &list, const std::vector<int> &ids)
{
     auto oldList = std::move(list);
     list = std::vector<Object>{};
     list.resize(oldList.size());
     for (Object &obj : oldList)
     {
         auto &newLocation = list[getIntendedIndex(ids, obj)];
         newLocation = std::move(obj);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objectList.sort([&idList] (const Object& o1, const Object& o2) -> bool
   { return std::find(++std::find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), o1.id),
       idList.end(), o2.id)
       != idList.end();
   });
```

The idea is to check if we find `o1.id` before `o2.id` in the `idList`.
We search `o1.id`, increment the found position then we search `o2.id`: if found, that implies o1 < o2.

**Test**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Object {
    int id;
    string name;
};

int main()
{
  list<Object> objectList {{1, "one_1"}, {2, "two_1"}, {3, "three_1"}, {2, "two_2"}, {1, "one_2"}, {4, "four_1"}, {3, "Three_2"}, {4, "four_2"}};
  list<int> idList {3, 2, 4, 1};

  objectList.sort([&idList] (const Object& o1, const Object& o2) -> bool
    { return std::find(++std::find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), o1.id), idList.end(), o2.id) != idList.end(); });

  for(const auto& o: objectList) cout << o.id << " " << o.name << "\n";
}

/* OUTPUT: 
3 three_1
3 Three_2
2 two_1
2 two_2
4 four_1
4 four_2
1 one_1
1 one_2
*/
```